# Django no valid form inside table

Tags: python, html, css, django

please help to resolve my issue. 
I have the form

```
<form method="post" id="post_request">
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

and in the middle of the page table, which get date to this form

```
<body>
....
<table>
<tr><td>
<p><input id="form.username" type="text" name="username" value=""></p>
<p><input id="form.email" type="text" name="email" value=""></p>
<p><input id="form.firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value=""></p>
<p><input id="form.lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value=""></p>
<p><input id="form.password" type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
<p><input id="form.password2" type="password" name="password2" value=""></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login" form="post_request" /></p>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

but after investigate, i find this forme stoped to be vaild and post are stuck on function `if form.is_valid():`.
After deeper investigate i find the issue in fields, they stoped to works and sedning no data. Why?

thanks

Comment: Why not have your inputs inside the form? is there a reason they're separate?

Comment: because form cant be inside the table.. but i must to put it :)

Comment: You essentially do have the form inside of the table.. I don't understand what you mean it can't be inside there

Comment: who told you to use tables anyway? Why can't you wrap the `input` tags inside the `form` tag? do you have access to the entire code? If you cannot place the inputs inside the form for some weird reason, you'll have to use javascript to get the values and insert them into the form submission data.. not very efficient